# Как выполнить все методы, имена которых указаны в массиве?

Tags: javascript

Есть массив с названиями методов. В конструкторе класса нужно запустить все эти методы по их именам. Например:

```
  class A {
      constructor(methods) {
        // methods == ["a", "c", "e"];
      }

      a() {
      }

      b() {
      }

      c() {
      }

      d() {
      }

      e() {
      }
  }
```

Необходимо, чтобы автоматически запустились и выполнились методы `a`, `c` и `e` этого класса. Запуск необходимо инициализировать прямо в конструкторе. Слышал, что можно использовать `eval`, но, вроде как, это плохое решение (но я не уверен). Короче говоря, ищу доступные варианты.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Внутри конструктора `this` указывает на создаваемый объект.

Для обращения к методу, имя которого находится в переменной, нужно использовать [скобочную нотацию](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors#%D0%A1%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F)

Для прохода по всем элементам массива - [forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

В итоге получится:

```
methods.forEach(method=>this[method]());
```

Comment: То, что я искал. Спасибо! Все время забываю, что можно "просто добавить скобки" :)

Answer (score 2):

```js
class A {
      constructor(methods) {
  for (var i = 0; i < methods.length; i ++) {
   this[methods[i]]();
  }
      }
      a() {
        console.log("a");
      }
      b() {
        console.log("b");
      }
      c() {
        console.log("c");
      }
      d() {
        console.log("d");
      }
      e() {
        console.log("e");
      }
}

new A(["a", "c", "e"]);
```